# Create a custom login functionality in WordPress for API authentication

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create a custom login functionality in WordPress. What I need is instead of using the default `user_pass` field in the `wp_users` table I want to use a custom user meta value from the `wp_usermeta` table. I know there is a `authenticate` filter hook in WordPress which can be used to write a custom authentication function. The problem is that the authentication I need is for the WordPress APIs. I will be using another application to access WordPress using the APIs. So after a user is authenticated then he can create/edit/delete posts. There is a plugin available for API authentication called [WP OAuth Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/). But that uses client id or username/password for authentication. Is there a way I can use the filter hook on this plugin? Or create a custom function for authenticating the user through APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve it by using the plugin [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/). The plugin supports authentication for WordPress API using username and password. So I used the `authenticate` filter to use my own custom login function.

```
function custom_auth_signon($user, $username, $password) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_details = get_user_by('login', $username);

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta WHERE user_id = " . $user_details->data->ID . " AND meta_key = 'custom_password' AND meta_value = %s", $password);
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    if ($result[0]->user_id) {
        return $user_details;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

}

add_filter('authenticate', 'custom_auth_signon', 30, 3);
```